# New tab not opening in flutter web on iOS environment (safari)

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I have a flutter web app with a button that opens a link in a new chrome (or any) tab. This button works fine in Windows/Android and iPhones but the issue comes up on iPads. When I click the button, it says loading (expected and working) but it doesn't open/redirect to the new link. I tried with flutter HTML package (works in Windows/Android and iPhones) but doesn't work on iPad again. Same with url_launcher package.

Is there any way to work this out?

You can check the deployed website [here](https://textel-technologies-pvt-af40e.web.app/#/).

If you scroll down the landing page, you'll find a `Brochure` button. Click on it and it opens a new page. Input email and phone (These data aren't stored or sent anywhere the backend isn't hooked up yet, just for validation). And click on get brochure. Check if it works on your iPad or so

Here are code snippets:

onPressed Function
[image: onPressed func]

Heres the validation method
[image: Validation]

Comment: I don't think anyone would just give their email address or phone number to download something they don't know what it is.

We'll need your code to help you with this problem...

Comment: @Th3Ph4nt0m I've added code snippets, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of research, I found that your problem may be due to asynchronous calling of a previous process<sup>[1]</sup>. Could you try commenting out the entire Firebase call and just link to https://flutter.dev/ instead? Once that works, we'll know where the problem is.

<sup>[1]</sup> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75227#issuecomment-771917971

Comment: Will try and let you know

Comment: So if I remove getting link from firebase async code and set url to constant, it works. But I'd be needing the link from firebase, how do we approach that?

Comment: What is `FirebaseMethods.getDownloadLink()`? Can you post the code pls?

Comment: FirebaseMethods is a custom class which uses .getDownloadLink from Firebase storage. Read more here https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files